# Triggering MOUSEDOWN event across all elements within container in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am making a sketchpad (Etch-a-sketch) that colors the blocks within the grid as you click and drag the cursor over them. For that, I used the mousedown event.

The problem I face is that even though I have applied the event to all the elements using a for loop, the mousedown events do not carry over to the other elements within the sketchpad container.

HTML

```
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Sketchpad 1.0</h1>
    </header>

    <main id="main">
        <div class="settings-panel">
          <button id="grid-size">CREATE GRID</button>
          <button class="hidden" id="pencil">PENCIL</button>
          <button class="hidden" id="rainbow">RAINBOW</button>
          <button class="hidden" id="eraser">ERASER</button>
          <button class="hidden" id="reset">RESET</button>
        </div>

        <div class="sketchpad">
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/guchierrez/" target="_blank">
        <img src="./icons/linkedin.png">
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com/guchierrez/etch-a-sketch" target="_blank">
        <img src="./icons/github.png">
      </a>
    </footer>
  </body>
```

JavaScript

```
/*========================================
======5. DRAWING BUTTON FUNCTIONALITY=====
=======PENCIL, RAINBOW AND ERASER=========
========================================*/

pencilButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
  for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    const blocks2 = document.getElementById(`block-${i}`);
    blocks2.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
      for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks2.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    });
  }
});

const colors = [
  "#9400D3",
  "#4B0082",
  "#0000FF",
  "#00FF00",
  "#FFFF00",
  "#FF7F00",
  "#FF0000",
];

rainbowButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
  for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    const blocks2 = document.getElementById(`block-${i}`);
    blocks2.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
      for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        let randomColors = colors[(colors.length * Math.random()) | 0];
        blocks2.style.backgroundColor = randomColors;
      }
    });
  }
});

eraserButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
  for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    const blocks2 = document.getElementById(`block-${i}`);
    blocks2.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
      for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks2.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
    });
  }
});
```

It works as intended with mouseover, but it colors indefinitely. I would like to be able to color only when the click button is pressed.

Comment: For performance reasons given the amount of mouseovers it'd be better to use a mouse over on the window object, and detect the event target. IT also solves your problem

Comment: you expect to have `blocks2` with a consistent value inside the `mousedown` event listener.. the correct way would be `event.target` instead, as long as you put `event` in the arguments of your listener function.